# How would I multiply two columns of a row and add that to another product of a row with a similar id?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I would need to multiply `numOrdered` (11) to `quotedPrice` (14.95), and since that row has the same `orderNum` as the next row I would add the product to the product of 1 and 399, and so on for every same `orderNum`.

```
| orderNum | partNum | numOrdered | quotedPrice |
|    12489 | ax12    |         11 |       14.95 |
|    12489 | bt04    |          1 |         399 |
|    12489 | bz66    |          3 |         300 |
|    12489 | cb03    |          5 |         170 |
|    12489 | cx11    |          1 |          60 |
```

Comment: When you say "the product of 1 and 399" do you mean "product" in the multiplication sense, i.e. the product of 2 and 3 is 6. I can't work out if it's a product (an iphone) or a product (an arithmetic)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking or what you're looking to accomplish here.

Comment: Yes, I do mean in a multiplication sense.

Comment: I want to multiply 11 and 14.95 and add that to 1 multiplied by 399, and do that for every row that has the same orderNum.

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: `SELECT something, SUM(anotherthing*yetanotherthing) total FROM somewhere GROUP BY something;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a pretty basic aggregation query:

```
select ordernum, sum(numOrdered * quotedPrice)
from t
group by ordernum;
```